# type cast MKUserLocation class to MKAnnotation protocol

Tags: iphone, ios, mkannotation

`mapView:viewForAnnotation:` method has a parameter named `annotation` (MKUserLocation). in my application i want to cast type this `annotation` to MKAnnotation.

i tried this:

```
-(MKAnnotationView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MyAnnotation *myAnnotation = (MyAnnotation*)annotation;
}
```

here MyAnnotation is a custom class which adopted `MKAnnotation` protocol. Problem is myAnnotation still a MKUserLocation type object. I want `myAnnotation` as an MKAnnotation object. How to type cast this? please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The `viewForAnnotation` delegate method is called for *all* annotations regardless of their type.  This includes the map view's own user location blue dot annotation which is of type `MKUserLocation`.

Before casting `annotation` or trying to treat it like your custom class, you need to check if the current `annotation` is of the type you are interested (or not).

For example:

```
-(MKAnnotationView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{
    if (! [annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]])
    {
        //return nil (ie. default view) 
        //if annotation is NOT of type MyAnnotation...
        //this includes MKUserLocation.
        return nil;
    }


    //If execution reached this point, 
    //you know annotation is of type MyAnnotation
    //so ok to treat it like MyAnnotation...

    MyAnnotation *myAnnotation = (MyAnnotation*)annotation;

    //create and return custom MKAnnotationView here...
}
```